# Response.Redirect Inside Try/Catch Block

Tags: c#, asp.net

While trying to `convert strting into enum` in Asp.NET webApplication.

Code -

```
enum MyEnum
{
    field1,
    field2,
    field3
}

string strField1 = "field1";
MyEnum parsedEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), strField1);
```

I encounter following error -

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack.

What am I missing.

EDIT: Updated Code:

I have been using this enum to redirect user to other page, by validating CommandArgument of the button. I obtain this error while debugging the solution, other-wise the code works fine.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="Redirect" ID="btnRedirect" OnClick="btnRedirect_Click" CommandName="field1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>



    protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var cmdName = btn.CommandName; //field1
        MyEnum parsedEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), cmdName);

        try
        {
            switch (parsedEnum)
            {
                case MyEnum.field1:
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
                    break;
                case MyEnum.field2:
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
                    break;
                case MyEnum.field3:
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm3.aspx");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var err = ex.Message;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take out the (MyEnum) - you're already telling it what type to parse as

Comment: When do you encounter that error?  I suspect that you are not getting that error from your running code; that's an error you typically see in a debugger when trying to inspect something.

Comment: Code is correct. I executed that successfully

Comment: @Darren, that's not true, this method return an 'object' so should be casted to the actual Enum type after parsing. The code in the question is correct. There is an Enum.TryParse which is generic, if you wanted to though.

Comment: Is there not more code that is relevant? If you put that code in Page_Load you get that error?

Comment: Your code as posted executes fine in Linqpad.  Are you certain you've pasted your exact code?

Comment: @Darren `Enum.Parse` returns an `object`.

Comment: Same code is working fine working for me in debug mode.

Comment: Maybe the question asker should clean out the obj/bin folders, maybe restart their Visual Studio (and/or IIS process) and try again.

Comment: @autrevo: What exactly is happening?  Your code itself is *not* throwing this error - your code is working.  But it seems as though you are trying to debug the value - maybe in a watch or the immediate window - and *that* is when you're seeing the error.

Comment: @RenéWolferink, yep, you're right. I had a brain-fart :)

Comment: @ autrevo, try to debug on other computer. May be it is a strange bug local net framework.

Comment: Have you tried my solution below?

Comment: @JoeyGennari Thanks, your solution actually guided towards resolution, This had been actually the issue with using `Response.Redirect` inside `try/catch` block. +1, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue lied in trying to redirect to other page, inside `try catch` block.

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack.

Above exception had been caused, inside catch block, the `current page thread was being aborted.`

Answer (score 1):

All references to that error message point to adding a second, `false` parameter to `Request.Redirect`. Is the `enum` code redirecting the user?

Comment: yes, I have been using MyEnum, insided switch case, and Response.Redirect as well.

Comment: So change your `Response.Redirect(url)` to `Response.Redirect(url, false)` and you should be good.